# Retrieving Data from Facebook but Unable to Get Email

Tags: objective-c, facebook, email

I know this question has been asked earlier many times but i am unable to find any scenario similar to mine. I am retrieving data from Facebook and successfully getting response as well. The issue is with email only. I am getting null in email only. Everything else is fine.

Here is my code through which I am retrieving data:

```
    NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"];
    SLRequest *feedRequest = [SLRequest
                              requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                              requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                              URL:feedURL
                              parameters:nil];
    feedRequest.account = self.facebookAccount;
    [feedRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData,
                                             NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
     {
         // Handle response
         if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200) {
             NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             NSDictionary *userInfoDictionary = [responseString JSONValue];
             FacebookUser *currentFacebookUser = [[FacebookUser alloc] init];

             NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
             [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
             currentFacebookUser.userId = [f numberFromString:[userInfoDictionary objectForKey:@"id"]];
             currentFacebookUser.firstName = [userInfoDictionary objectForKey:@"first_name"];
             currentFacebookUser.last_name = [userInfoDictionary objectForKey:@"last_name"];
             currentFacebookUser.username = [userInfoDictionary objectForKey:@"username"];
             currentFacebookUser.email = [userInfoDictionary objectForKey:@"email"];

             [self.delegate facebookUserInformationRequestCompleted:YES facebookUser:currentFacebookUser];
         } else {
             [self.delegate facebookUserInformationRequestCompleted:NO facebookUser:nil];
         }
     }];
```

I get following result:

```
        {"id":"12345678","name":"Abc Xyz","first_name":"Abc","last_name":"Xyz",
"link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/ABC12345",
    "birthday":"09\/09\/1990","hometown":{"id":"12345678",
    "name":"New York, New York"},
    "location":{"id":"12345678","name":"New York, New York"},
    "work":[{"employer":{"id":"12345678","name":"Walmart"},
    "location":{"id":"12345678","name":"Bentonville, Arkansas"},
    "start_date":"0000-00"}],"favorite_athletes":[{"id":"12345678","name":"xyzabc"}],
    "gender":"female","timezone":5,"locale":"en_US",
    "verified":true,"updated_time":"2014-02-10T06:03:36+0000",
    "username":"abc123"}
```

I have edited the names and ids, But I am getting correct names and other data is also fine. But I cannot see email address which was supposed to be after gender, if I am not wrong.

So can any one tell me, where I am wrong?

Comment: have you tried them with different facebook accounts? .. as you can put you email as private and can not accessed by facebook api.

Comment: it gives email for some accounts but not for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `remote_app_id` and your bundle id. They should be same. If they are not, you will not get permissions.

Check your method where you are asking for permissions. There you can check whether you are getting access permission or not. If you are not getting permission then it might the `remote_app_id` issue.

Comment: Oh, I had changed my bundle id but not the remote id. Thanks you got my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Ask for user permission to access their email id's
[Look for Permissions here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/permissions/)

Permission you need to access email is "email" refer the link.